# porting existing iOS app to UWP

Tags: ios, macos, uwp

I have source code for an iOS app and I am trying to port it to UWP.

I am using "Windows bridge for iOS(https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bridges/ios)" to port it but this does not help. It creates a visual studio solution but that has many compilation errors. There are missing header files and many identifiers deemed as "Unknown keywords". I tried adding the header files but then it seems like visual studio is not able to understand objective C. For example in below line of code, I get error "unknown type name 'UINTN'"

```
    typedef UINTN   ULONGN;
```

There are many such similar errors.

I compiled and ran the same code on Mac OS using XCode and it runs fine.

Is there any alternative way to port this to UWP? or any way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Bridge for iOS is not intended to port existing iOS apps to Windows. Its sole purpose is to allow for iOS development under a Windows machine. That being said, this will not help you in any way.

You will have to resort to manual porting. UWP and iOS are fundamentally different in app architecture, so I would expect major amendments to the existing codebase during porting.

Comment: Thank you Dmitry Serov but i'm new to objective C and visual studio does not understand obj-c too much.Any guidance how to bring support for obj-c in visual studio

Comment: @shaguftasyed Visual Studio does not support Objective-C.